# Simplest way to transform a nested list of 31 dataframes into 31 individual dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big list consisting of 31 nested dataframes. Each list dataframe has two strings: timestamp and measurement data. I want to convert them into individial dataframes.

Screen shot of biglist
[image]

```
biglist = [list1,list2,.........list31]

df1 = biglist[0]
.
.
df31 = biglist[30]
print(df1)
02/01/2019 09:30:23.000    26.77196
02/01/2019 10:10:32.000    59.66217
02/01/2019 10:50:32.000    85.40406
02/01/2019 11:30:32.000    61.95119
```

Now I am typing 31 lines to do it. Is there a simplest way of doing it? using for loop? etc.

Based on below accepted answer from @`WeNYoBen`, I am using dictionary to call each dataframe. For iterating through dictionary, I am doing this

```
df=dict(enumerate(biglist1[1]))
    for i,x in df:
#        print(i,x)
        df[i] = df[i].apply(pd.to_numeric)
        df[i].index = pd.to_datetime(df[i].index)
```

It is working successfully with no errors. 
Now I want to combine data from 24 dataframes only. Code is

```
df[0]['time']=df[0].index  ### considering POA as reference dataframe
df[0]['time'] = df[0]['time'].apply(pd.to_datetime) # print(df[0].index) # print(dfm24.index) dfm1.dtypes
l=[]
s1 = []
for i,x in enumerate(df):           ## dfm24.duplicated(subset=None, keep='first')
    s1=df[0].reindex(df[i].index,method='nearest')
    b = 1
    if i>8:
        b = 2
    if i==1:
        l.append(s1.join(df[i]).set_index('time').add_suffix(df[i].columns[0][-b:]))
    if (i > 1) & (i<25):
        l.append(s1.join(df[i]).set_index('time').reindex(l[0].index,method='nearest').add_suffix(df[i].columns[0][-b:]))
combdf = pd.concat(l,1) # combdf.dtypes
```

This code is working successfully with no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not safe but work

```
variables = locals()

for i,j in enumerate(biglist) :
    variables["df{0}".format(i+1)] = j
```

More safety way is to save it into dict

```
d=dict(enumerate(biglist))
d[0]
```

---

Update

```
df=dict(enumerate(biglist1))
for i,x in df:
    print(i,x)
    df[i] = df[i].apply(pd.to_numeric)
    df[i].index = pd.to_datetime(df[i].index)
```

Comment: I don't know why the first approach is not safe. So I prefer to use `dict` your second approach. My question is, how to access individual data frames and use them later?

Comment: @Msquare do with d[0] get the df by dict key

Comment: I want to change index in each dataframe to  proper `datetime` and associated data to `float`. Now should I run a for loop?

Comment: After trial and error I found the root cause of the problem and issue is solved. Now it is working successfully. I updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: Could you check my another question at     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57031232/renaming-30-dataframes-columns/57031375#57031375

Comment: @Msquare check whether it work or not , I have add one solution

Comment: could you check my new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57049769/comparing-two-dataframe-columns-of-booleans

Comment: Could you check my updated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57049769/comparing-two-dataframe-columns-of-booleans