# Renaming 30 dataframes columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 30 data frames and each `df` has a column. The column names are big and look something like as given below:

```
df1.columns =  ['123.ABC_xyz_1.CB_1.S_01.M_01.Pmax']
df2.columns =  ['123.ABC_xyz_1.CB_1.S_01.M_02.Pmax']
..
df30.columns =  ['123.ABC_xyz_1.CB_1.S_01.M_30.Pmax']
```

I want to trim their names and I want them finally to be something like as given below:

```
df1.columns =  ['M1Pmax']
df2.columns =  ['M2Pmax']
..
df30.columns =  ['M30Pmax']
```

I thought of something like this:

```
df_list = [df1,df2,....,df30]
for i,k in enumerate(df_list):
    df_list[i].columns = [col_name+'_df[i]{}'.format(df_list[i]) for col_name in df_list[i].columns]
```

However, my above code is not working properly.

How to do it?

Comment: @WeNYoBen can you look at this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the dataframe itself in the name which is not gonna work. I am assuming you were trying to use the name of the dataframe. You are also not shortening anything in your code but just making it longer. I would suggest something like:

```
df_list = [df1,df2,....,df30]
for i, k in enumerate(df_list):
    df_list[i].columns = ['M{}_'.format(i)+col_name.split(".")[-1] for col_name in df_list[i].columns]
```

Comment: I tried your method and I got following: `df[1].columns = 
['__df_df1']`. I was expecting `df[1].columns = 
['M1_Pmax']`. Any idea where it is wrong?

Comment: Your updated answer gave me following output: `df[1].columns =['M1_fdf1']`. I was expecting `df[1].columns = ['M1_Pmax']`

Comment: That means that this `df1.columns =  ['123.ABC_xyz_1.CB_1.S_01.M_01.Pmax']` is not true. Show me what is actually the column name.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
l=[]

for i in df_list:

  i.columns=i.columns.str.split('.').str[-2:].str.join('').str.replace('_','')
  l.append(i)
```

Comment: I got following error: `i.columns=i.columns.str.split('.').str[-2:].str.join('').str.replace('_','')

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'columns'`

Comment: @Msquare is df_list a list of dfs ?

Comment: Yes! it is working. I am getting this output: `df[1].columns= 
['fdf1']`. But I am expecting something like this `df[1].columns= 
['M01']`

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing it like this?

```
# List of all dataframes
df_list = [df1,df2,....,df30]
# List of Columns names for all dataframes
colum_names =[['M1Pmax'],['M2Pmax'],...., ['M30Pmax']]

for i in range(len(df_list)):
    df_list[i].columns = [colum_names[i]]
```

Hope this will help you!.

Comment: It is a laborious procedure. Need simple.