# comparing two dataframe columns of booleans

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes each denoting actual rain and predicted rain condition. Actual rain dataframe is constant as it is a known result. Predicted rain dataframe They are given below.

```
actul = 

index  rain
Day1   True
Day2   False
Day3   True
Day4   True
```

Predicted rain dataframe is given below. This dataframe keeps on changing based on predicted model used.

```
prdt = 

index  rain
Day1   False
Day2   True
Day3   True
Day4   False
```

I am developing prediction accuracy of above prediction model as given below:

```
#Following computes the number days on which raining was predicted correctly        
a = sum(np.where(((actul['rain'] == True)&(prdt['rain']==True)),True,False))  
#Following computes the number days on which no-rain was predicted correctly    
b = sum(np.where(((actul['rain'] == False)&(prdt['rain']==False)),True,False))
#Following computes the number days on which raining was incorrectly predicted 
c = sum(np.where(((actul['rain'] == True)&(prdt['rain']==False)),True,False))
#Following computes the number days on which no-rain was incorrectly predicted     
d = sum(np.where(((actul['rain'] == False)&(prdt['rain']==True)),True,False))

predt_per =  (a+b)*100/(a+b+c+d)
```

My above code is taking too much time to compute. Is there a better way to achieve above result?

Now, below accepted answer solved my above problem. Looks like something is wrong in my code given below because I am getting `100%` prediction percentage for all dataframes. My code is:

```
alldates_df = 

index       met1_r2    useful     met1_r2>0.5
0          0.824113     True        True
1          0.903828     True        True
2          0.500765     True        True
3          0.889757     True        True
4          0.890102     True        True
5          0.893995     True        True
6          0.933482     True        True
7          0.872847     True        True
8          0.913142     True        True
9          0.901424     True        True
10         0.910941     True        True
11         0.927310     True        True
12         0.934538     True        True
13         0.946092     True        True
14         0.653831     True        True
15         0.390702     True        False
16         0.878493     True        True
17         0.899739     True        True
18         0.938481     True        True
19      -850.978703     False       False
20       -21.802518     False       False

met1_detacu = [] # Method1_detection accuracy at various settings
var_flset = np.arange(-5,1,0.01) # various filter settings
for i in var_flset:
    pdt_usefl =  alldates_df.assign(result=alldates_df['met1_r2']>i)
    x = pd.concat([alldates_df['useful'],pdt_usefl['result']],axis=1).sum(1).isin([0,2]).mean()*100
    met1_detacu.append(x)
plt.plot(var_flset,met1_detacu)
```

My above code is working fine but I am getting but I am getting all `100%` detection accuracy at all the `varible filter settings`. Something is wrong here.
Obtained plot: 
[image]

Expected plot is:

[image]

@WeNYoBen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case assuming the index is the index of df , so we can using `sum` after `concat` , since True + True ==2 and False + False ==0

```
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1).sum(1).isin([0,2]).mean()*100
25.0
```

---

Update

```
met1_detacu = [] # Method1_detection accuracy at various settings
var_flset = np.arange(-5,1,0.01) # various filter settings
for i in var_flset:
    pdt_usefl =  alldates_df.assign(result=alldates_df['met1_r2']>i)
    x = pd.concat([alldates_df['useful'],pdt_usefl['result']],axis=1).sum(1).isin([0,2]).mean()*100
    met1_detacu.append(x)
plt.plot(var_flset,met1_detacu)
```

Comment: I am surprised to look at this single line code. Is this the prediction percentage am I asking for?

Comment: @Msquare you can check your output and match with this :-)

Comment: If you don't mind, did you already know that this gives prediction percentage. Of course, in above example, `a=1,b=0,c=2,d=1 and predt_per=25%`. I am surprised and puzzled. How did you know this?

Comment: @Msquare I just reading thru your code , then find out that is more like mean problem after we know the combination value with sum

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I updated my question to include my second doubt. Could you check it?

Comment: @Msquare ummm would you like show us some data about your follow up question?

Comment: I updated my question with some data and expected detection accuracy plot. I hope you got it.

Comment: Did you check my updated question? I have provided some data and expected plot? I would like to hear from you

Comment: @Msquare hi my friend I am in US  ...time zone diff will look into it

Comment: Sorry, I interrupted your time. Anyhow, thanks for the response.

Comment: @Msquare I think that should be right , 100, since you match the df row by row, True will match with True and False will match with False , the two df here are identical

Comment: It depends on `var_flset`. Suppose, if `var_flset=0.5`, we get few more False because there are values which are less than `0.5`. For instance, I updated my question. Please, check it.

Comment: Could you check my new question here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57081153/converting-many-txt-files-into-csv-and-combining-them

Comment: Could you check my new question here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57115895/python-combining-different-csv-files-of-different-timestamps-on-timestamp-wise-a