# Converting many .txt files into csv and combining them

Tags: python, csv

I have many .txt files. I want to convert a few files ending with specific names into csv and combine them into one csv.

```
### Folder Name: text_files
python_gramm.py
aadd01.txt
aaxx02.txt
aaff03.txt
hhdd01.txt
attd02.txt
auud03.txt
.
.
```

A text file contains columns of data as given below:
[image]

I would like to convert only those `.txt` files having name '___01.txt' to csv format and combine them
My code

```
#### python_gramm.py 
import os
import glob
    os.chdir('text_files/')
    extension = 'txt'
    all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*01.{}'.format(extension))]
    #combine all files in the list
    combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='\t') for f in all_filenames ])
    #export to csv
    combined_csv.to_csv( "combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Above code ran successfully without errors.

```
print(combined_csv)
0      4.18890   9.325750  ...  2.438860e-05            4.100250e+04
1      4.21399   9.339870  ...  2.461170e-05            4.063090e+04
2      4.26399   9.341690  ...  2.451400e-05            4.079280e+04
3      4.80021   9.346420  ...  2.442850e-05            4.093570e+04
4      6.50219   9.339300  ...  2.432250e-05            4.111400e+04
```

Comment: @MarkTolonen This gave error. However, my above code now ran successfully but new problem. I updated my q

Comment: If you update your question so it has working code and the answer, then the question isn't a question anymore.  It also makes the answer no longer make sense because there is no reference to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code says

```
glob.glob('1.{}'.format(extension))
```

But I think you mean

```
glob.glob('*01.{}'.format(extension))
```

I don't think your glob is finding any files named "1.txt".

Comment: I notice you edited so as to give '01' but you also need the asterisk.

Comment: Yes! now it did ran successfully. But one more error. I updated my question.

Comment: Yes! now it ran successfully but new problem came. I updated my question. Could you check it.

Comment: Sorry I can't get the whole thing running right now, but try unpacking that comprehension so you can see exactly where it's failing.  Rewrite with each step on a separate line until it works, then you can put it back together so it's pretty and Pythonic :)

Comment: The code is running is successfully. But only problem is, `.csv` file has unexpected `\t` in between the columns. I have shown a sample of output in  my question. Any guess, where to mention about delimiter?

Comment: I don't use Panda (yet) but is there a way to tell read_csv what kind of separator to expect?

Comment: Yes! I solved it and now it is working. I updated my question. Thanks